# Probability of choosing married couples

Tags: probability

k married couples (pairs) arrived at a party.

An even number m of the 2k people were chosen at random.

Compute the probability that:

a) Among the chosen ones there is no married couple.

b) Among the chosen ones there is exactly one married couple.

c) Among the chosen ones there are exactly 4 married couples, assuming of course that m ≥ 8.

d) All the chosen ones are m/2 married couples.

I think that A can be:

$\binom{k}{m}$$*$$2^m$$/$$\binom{2k}{m}$

B) $\binom{k-1}{m-2}$$*k*$$2^{(m-2)}$$/$$\binom{2k}{m}$

C) $\binom{k}{4}$$\binom{k-4}{m-8}$$*$$2^{(m-8)}$$/$$\binom{2k}{m}$

D)  $\binom{k}{m/2}$/$\binom{2k}{m}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this looks okay.

> > a) Among the chosen ones there is no married couple.
>
> $\binom{k}{m}\cdot 2^m / \binom{2k}{m}$

This is the probability for selecting $1$ partner for each of $m$ from $k$ couples, when selecting $m$ from $2k$ people.   Check.

> > b) Among the chosen ones there is exactly one married couple.
>
> $\binom{k-1}{m-2}\cdot k\cdot 2^{(m-2)}/\binom{2k}{m}$

This is the probability for selecting $1$ married couple from the $k$ couples and $1$ partner for each of the $m-2$ from the remaining $k-1$, when selecting $m$ from $2k$ people.   Check.

> > c) Among the chosen ones there are exactly 4 married couples, assuming of course that m ≥ 8.
>
> $\binom{k}{4} \binom{k-4}{m-8}\cdot 2^{(m-8)} / \binom{2k}{m}$

This is the probability for selecting $4$ married couples from the $k$ couples, and $1$ partner for each of the $m-8$ from the remaining $k-4$ couples, when selecting $m$ from $2k$ people.   Check.

> > d) All the chosen ones are m/2 married couples.

As above.   You've done this for "exactly none", "exactly $1$", and "exactly $4$".  Now do so for "exactly $m/2$".

Comment: thank you for that answers. I didn't understand what is wrong? b and c? or everything is good so far?

Comment: Everything checks okay so far. @TalShani

Comment: thank you. i just added my answer for D

Comment: @TalShani Yeap, and that's okay too.